# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android when trying to add multiple dependencies

Tags: android, gradle

I am learning right now with 1.5 year old Udemy guide that I just bought about all kinds of advanced android stuff. I got to the point where I need to load a bunch of 3rd party librarys, so I did it according to the guide and got the following erroes:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android
Affected Modules: app


WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
Remove Build Tools version and sync project
Affected Modules: app
```

here is my project level gradle -

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = '26.0.2'
    minSdkVersion = 23
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibraryVersion = '26.1.0'
    daggerVersion = '2.11'
    retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'
    moshiVersion = '1.5.0'
    autoValueVersion = '1.5.1'
    autoValueMoshiVersion = '0.4.3'
    rxJavaVersion = '2.1.4'
    rxAndroidVersion = '2.0.1'
    rxRelayVersion = '2.0.0'
    conductorVersion = '2.1.4'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here is my app level gradle -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.androidadvanced1"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design'$supportLibraryVersion"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:$moshiVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-moshi:$autoValueMoshiVersion"
    compileOnly "com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-moshi-annotations:$autoValueMoshiVersion"

    compileOnly "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:$autoValueVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:$autoValueVersion"

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxAndroidVersion"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:$rxRelayVersion"

    implementation "com.bluelinelabs:conductor:$conductorVersion"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Update your Gradle pal,  your Android studio version,  gradle and dependency should be matched.

Comment: alright so I updated the buildToolsVersion and the 2nd error dissapeared but right now I am still stuck with the first one - ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.  What should fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that some of your dependencies rely on each other and you might have conflicting version numbers. For eg. you might have dependency *x* which might require a certain version of dependency *y*, but you instead have another version of dependency *y* installed. So, do check if there are any conflicting version numbers with the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a quick check for that with the IDE?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. I once had an error like that and the problem was with conflicting version numbers, and I remember posting a question similar to this on this site before. I would recommend searching on google and try to find out what versions of dependencies are required for certain dependencies; alternatively, since you are using Udemy, you can leave a comment in the Q&A of the course, and the course instructor will help you out. I will also help you check now. Happy coding!